# Showing a custom offline page only in angular pwa when no internet connection is available

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, offline, offline-caching

in Angular 9+ i would like to add a custom offline page (.html and .scss file).I have converted my angular app into a pwa by following all basic steps which are required for an angular pwa .
But however i'am having trouble with the pwa. I already applied a connection service interface to monitor network connectivity in app.component.ts . the offline page execute when there is no network but the moment i press refresh button the browser refreshes without showing any offline . I want to implement the offline in such a way that if user press the refresh link the browser refresh but also show the same offline page if there is no network.
[Angular PWA with custom offline page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163206/angular-pwa-with-custom-offline-page?answertab=votes#tab-top) (i tried creating a custom sw.js but it always give me an registration error ).

app.component.ts

```
constructor( connectionService:ConnectionService) {
            this.conCheck()
           }
conCheck(){
this.connectionService.monitor().subscribe( conn => {
  this.isConnection = conn;
  if(this.isConnection){
    this.util.showSuccess("You are Connected.")
  }else{
    this.util.showError("Please check your internet connection.")
  }
})
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="isConnection ; else offline">
<router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
<ng-template #offline>
<app-network-checker></app-network-checker></ng-template>
```

ngsw-config.json

```
"files": [
      "/favicon.ico",
      "/*.css",
      "/*.js",
      "/assets/offline.html"
    ]
```

app.module.ts

```
imports: [
  ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production , registrationStrategy:"registerImmediately" })
```

network-checker.component.html (offline page)

```
<main>
<a href="#">refresh</a>
</maine>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a route guard that uses the ConnectionService to check status on each attempt to route.  That's probably the easier solution and the route guard would be re-usable for all routes.

Comment: thank you james for your reply and help.
My apologies for the late reply from my side