# Angular Progressive Web App(PWA) offline not work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps

According to the official documents, I try to build a PWA work in the offline environment, I can do this with pure PWA without angular-cli.

But I followed official documents, It can't run offline. It's that document
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#getting-started-with-service-workers

My angular-cli version: @angular/cli@8.3.17

My code https://github.com/unnhao/pwa-test

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: @Tony Ngo https://github.com/unnhao/pwa-test

Comment: Does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56735905/angular-pwa-route-to-custom-offline-page-when-no-connection-available/56738140?noredirect=1#comment105507894_56738140) solve your problem ?

Comment: Still not work.

Comment: r u running your project on localhost? Let's ng build --prod.

Comment: Yes, I just follow official doc and running on localhost, maybe run at real https server can solve it?

Comment: Note: If you are not using HTTPS, the service worker will only be registered when accessing the app on localhost.

have u built prod ?

Comment: workflow in angular docs: ng build --prod -> http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/<project-name> -> check Audits on deverloper tool

Comment: I found a very weird thing, this morning it can run and looks very normal. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually registering the service worker.
In your src/main.ts change the following:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

to.........

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Sorry for the  formatting, this is my first official answer. I had this same issue and tried a bunch of different things. This is the only solution that worked for me. I originally found the solution here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13351